# Alternative day for Upakarma when one misses it

Tags: vedic-rituals

If one misses the Yearly Upakarma (sacred thread changing ceremony) rituals on that given day, is there any alternative day one can perform that  ?  After one week or month ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You have to do it compulsorily on the UpAkarma day.

Comment: The thread changing is done on many occasions related to coming out of uncleanliness (soothakam) such as birth of a child, death in the family etc. Those are more or less done on the next available good day.

Comment: You can change in the next  month avittam star or Poornima if you miss the yearly upakarma by telling the sankalpam.

Answer (score 2):

In my previous answers [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19493/7853) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19414/7853) I have given the information related to upAkarma. You can understand that different people belonging to different vedas and shAkhAs do it on different days.

If someone misses the upAkarma, he can perform in the next Poornima / full moon.

I am adding a message from one Sri Vaishnava [website](http://www.ramanuja.org/sv/bhakti/archives/aug98/0074.html), though it doesn't have scripture reference but this custom is followed by all.

> If for any reason you have missed performing the upAkarma on
>   Avani-Avittam (for eg. Grahanam etc.,), you can perform it on the next
>   pournami day. Upakarma is best performed in a river (rather than in a
>   temple).  This year at Buffalo, 20 of us joined together and performed
>   the upAkarma on the Niagara river at the Beaver Island State Park.  It
>   was a great experience and everyone of us enjoyed it.   For a moment I
>   thought the river must have felt thankful for serving the cause of
>   Sanatana Dharma!

Comment: +1 for " For a moment I thought the river must have felt thankful for serving the cause of Sanatana Dharma!"